# Is there a way to auto select filename when creating file in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, file, filenames

When I create a new file in Visual Studio with the wizard, I expect it to "auto-select" the filename, so I can immediately start typing the filename. I automatically do this as I use a lot of programs and such that do have this feature and let me type it directly after clicking on a new file, for example, Windows Explorer.

I hope I am clear about the problem, it would be great if someone knows someway to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a class. You could right click on a location in your Solution Explorer -> Add -> Class. This way the file creation wizard knows the type to create and thus will focus on the filename.

The "New Item" file creation wizard requires you to find a file type to create first. That's why the filename is not selected at first.

I hope this answers your question.